# Program / browser extension to analyze the impact of each browser extension on Gmail loading time

Tags: web-browser, gmail

I am looking for a program or browser extension that can analyze the impact of each browser extension on loading time of the Gmail interface, preferably in Google Chrome and supporting Windows 7.

Comment: The closest thing I've found is this web page by the creator of uBlock Origin, but you need to manually disable, refresh, re-run, and take deltas: http://raymondhill.net/ublock/pageloadspeed.html